# PHP script resulting in ssl error

Tags: php, ssl, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am attempting to install the Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#prerequisites

I've completed all the steps and when I perform the final action the "php quickstart.php" command in composer it provides me with a link that must be followed to get access to the api 
example

[image]

---

[image]

After entering this code however it providies me with this SSL error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright threw 2 hours of research and reading the error messages a lot I have located a solution. I had to install a cacert.pem file inside my php folder and go into my php.ini and locate curl.cainfo and uncomment it and provide the file path to the cacert.pem file. I'm extremely confused on why I didn't have one to begin with considering I reinstalled composer and my server like 2 times sooo idk. If this helps anyone in the future your welcome.